# Codeigniter: how to get data between today and last 15 days from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

my database table looks like below

`| id | user_name | address | contact |   date   |
 |----|-----------|---------|---------|----------|
 | 1  | john      |  NY     |  12345  |2015-4-20 |
 | 2  | Mart      |  NY     |  54345  |2015-4-05 |
 | 3  | Drew      |  US     |  67340  |2015-3-14 |`

my `controller` function is

```
function orders()
{

  $data['orders'] = $this->common_model->get_data_between_15days('tbl_orders',array('status'=>'1'));
  $data['title']='Orders';
  $data['main_content']='users/orders_view.php';
  $this->load->view('admin/includes/template',$data);

}
```

and my `model` function is

```
   public function get_data_between_15days($table, $condition)
   { 

    $result = $this->db->get_where($table, $condition);
    if($result)
      {
        return $result->result_array();
      }
   }
```

now i want to get the records between today and last 15 days from database.and  i tried like this

```
 $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW(); AND '.$condition);
```

but its not working. i want to get all the Records between Last 15  and 30 Days too.  I would appreciate for your help. thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use CodeIgniter standard of query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW()');
$this->db->where($conditions);
$result = $this->db->get($table);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve:

```
$qs = "";
if( is_array($condition) && count($condition) > 0 ):
    foreach( $condition as $_k => $_v ) {
        $qs .= "and $_k = {$_v} ";
    }
endif;

'SELECT * FROM '.$table.'  
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW() '.$qs
```

Comment: thank you `jogesh_pi`. but it's showing the error `Message: Array to string conversion`

Comment: @SujanShrestha that is because `$condition` holds the array data

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to get last 15 days data based on your localhost time zone as may be your MYSQL database time zone is different than your localhost then you will not get correct data from database.

```
 $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE date >= '.date('Y-m-d', time() - (15 * 24 * 60 * 60)).' AND date <= '.date('Y-m-d').' AND '.$condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` semicolon after `NOW()` function, semicolon is break query so YySql understand another query after semicolon
this query would work

```
 $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' 
 WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW() AND '.$condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way You can use dateiff to get any query between any two dates by days like this

```
    $result  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE datediff('". $your_date ."', row_date) <= 15")->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer to CI 4 at 2021

```
$myModel = new WhateverModel();

$result = $myModel->where("date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW()")->findAll();
```